# Where can i find Rest API functional testing with jmeter projects for reference?

Tags: rest, testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I am new to REST API functional testing and i am trying to automate it with jmeter.I need few functional API testing projects with jmeter for reference to proceed further.

Comment: Good starting points are : https://www.testingexcellence.com/jmeter-tutorial-testing-rest-web-services/ and http://www.testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter/

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter is usually used for Performance Testing, but it does offer wonderful support for Restful API testing.
Other Alternative and very popular choice being used these days is POSTMAN, you can find details here @ https://www.guru99.com/postman-tutorial.html

As shared in comments these are some good starting points for you.

1. [testingexcellence.com/jmeter-tutorial-testing-rest-web-services](https://testingexcellence.com/jmeter-tutorial-testing-rest-web-services)
2. [testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter](https://testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter)

And it won't be that easy that people will share the JMX scripts, that you can load to Jmeter and edit

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply I have already covered the basics.  I am looking for complete project to understand the structure and complete flow.